# How to get every byte array from ImageFile in parse?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm trying to store each byte array from an image file in parse to a temporary array but it's not storing the values for some reason. Here is my code:

```
values=new ArrayList<>(); 
final ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ImageUpload");
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> eventsList, com.parse.ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            //looping through the parse table and storing vlaues.
            for (int index = 0; index < eventsList.size(); index++) {
                ParseFile file=(ParseFile)eventsList.get(index).get("ImageFile");
                file.getDataInBackground(new GetDataCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(byte[] bytes, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                        //my problem
                        tmpBytes=bytes;
                        }
                    }
                });
                 //ListRow is a class which im trying to save each byte array value to ,its constructor takes 2 strings and a byte array
                values.add(new ListRow(eventsList.get(index).get("Title").toString(), eventsList.get(index).get("Description").toString(),tmpBytes));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `get("ImageFile")` this returns only file id. Use `getParseFile("ImageFile")` instead.

Also the code with `values.add` gets executed *before* you get your data because you download those asynchronously. In order to fix that put this code inside the `GetDataCallback` (forget `tmpBytes`).

Comment: Yes thank you very much that's the problems threads arent synchronized,could you please tell me what did you mean by put this code inside the GetDataCallback(forget tmpBytes) i didnt' understand what you meant by that

Comment: Never mind i've solved it,by deleting the getDataInBackground and just doing getData from the parsefile,and thanks alot for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. It is not very clean but it will probably work. I don't know what your app does but this solution is still not ideal. However, I would strongly reccomend to learn more about asynchrounous code execution, it would help you a lot.